# : not found shell scriptproblem

Tags: shell

I am trying some shell script for importing services and routes to our system. Below 2 functions then called with parameters.

```
import_service() {
    IMPORT_SERVICE=$1
    IMPORT_URL=$2

    REQUESTRETURN=$(curl "http://pcname:8080/services/$IMPORT_SERVICE")

    if [[ "$REQUESTRETURN" == "$NOTFOUND" ]]; then
        curl --location --request POST "http://pcname:8080/services/" \
        -d 'name='$IMPORT_SERVICE'' \
        -d 'url='$IMPORT_URL''
    else
        >&2 echo "Service $IMPORT_SERVICE already exists"
    fi
}

import_route() {
     IMPORT_SERVICE=$1
     IMPORT_NAME=$2
     IMPORT_PATH=$3
     IMPORT_PRESERVE_HOST=$4
     IMPORT_STRIP_PATH=$5

    REQUESTRETURN=$(curl "http://pcname:8080/services/$IMPORT_SERVICE/routes/$IMPORT_NAME")

    if [[ "$REQUESTRETURN" == "$NOTFOUND" ]]; then
        curl --location --request POST "http://pcname:8080/services/$IMPORT_SERVICE/routes" \
        -d 'name='$IMPORT_NAME''\
        -d 'paths[]='$IMPORT_PATH'' \
        -d 'preserve_host='$IMPORT_PRESERVE_HOST'' \
        -d 'strip_path='$IMPORT_STRIP_PATH''
    else
        >&2 echo "Route for Service $IMPORT_SERVICE with Name $IMPORT_NAME already exists"
    fi
}
```

After running the sh file, I am faced with the below errors. Notice that line 40 is the end of the file. Thanks for the help

```
: not found:
 with Url Service
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
konga.sh: 40: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "then")
```

Comment: Your file has dos line endings. Remove them.

Comment: did not worked.

Comment: Aside from the fact that your functions would break if called with a parameter that contains a space (which is most likely not the reason for the error you get), did you already try to paste your whole script (not just the two functions) into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)?